# Using Qweb to generate pdf report in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, qweb

Hi Friends I have used Qweb to generate the pdf report in odoo 9 now i can download the pdf file but the file does not showing the data

[Generated PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upb3x.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="report_invoice">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
           <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                <div class="row"> 
                    <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size: 24px;font-weight: bold;">company </h2>
                         <p>This object's name is <span t-field="o.name"/></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t> 
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: What version of wkhtmltopdf are you running? Execute `wkhtmltopdf -V` if running on linux from the terminal. To ensure the report is working at all replace everything inside of your `page` div with a static `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>` to verify your report is working and properly setup with odoo. Next Add in data. You want wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 or higher.

Comment: Show us how you declare your report as mentioned in `https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html`

Comment: hi phillipstack i am using the version -- wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt) and i have tried it with the h1 but it also not worked

Comment: hi george i called the pdf download action while clicking the button download  here is my code to call the id     @api.multi
    def print_report(self):
        datas = {}
        if self._context is None:
            self._context = {}
            data = self.read()[0]
            datas = {
                    'ids': [],
                    'model':self._name,
                    'form': data
                    }
        return self.env['report'].get_action(self, 'module.report_invoice', data=datas)

Comment: hello phillipstack i tried this code the problem  was not fixed

Comment: hello phillipstack i tried this code the problem  was not fixed   <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t>          
                     <div class="page">    
                        <h1>Report For <t t-esc="o.name"/></h1>
                     </div>
                     </t>
        </t>

Answer (score 1):

i have changed the return of the function which will print the pfd it worked for me

```
return {
                        'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
                        'report_name': 'module.report_invoice',
                        'datas': datas,
                        }
```